# how could I reduce tables with same property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 7 table and all of them have same property.

- my tables : saturday,sunday,monday, .. , friday.
- Their property is sixToEight, EightToNine, .... .

Is there anyway to reduce tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Seprate tables as below

```
Table 1 - DaysMaster
DayId   DayName
1       Saturday
2       Sunday
3       Monday
.       ....

Table 2 - ShiftMaster
ShiftId   ShiftName
1         sixToEight
2         EightToNine

Table3 - DayShiftMapping
DayShiftMappingId  DaysId  ShiftId Activity
1                  1       1       NULL
2                  1       2       eating breakfast 
3                  2       2       running
```

here i have created two master table for days and shift and in last table you can insert shift details like daysId - Reference from table 1 and ShiftId - reference from table 2 and add extra column as per your requirement

Hope this help you !

Comment: yes it helped me so much thank you. now i have another problem. how can i make them dynamic. like manager can insert something in saturday - eightToNine => eating breakfast??

Comment: ok great ,if you want to add property and show to all days or you want to show only for particular days like Saturday only ?

Comment: yes. particular day.like ..  => Saturday-8 To 9: Eating breakfast ---------------------------------  sunday-8 To 9 : go running

Comment: for that you can add one property in Table3 , where you provide text box and user can add activity and save to database